# User defined but user.user_id undefined

Tags: javascript, express, passport.js

User is definitely defined, but `user.user_id` isn't. I'm using express.js and passport.js

```
router.post('/requestSale', function(req,res){
    console.log('session user: ' +  req.session.passport.user); //logs 
    console.log('session user_id: ' + req.session.passport.user.user_id);
    api.initiateSale(req.body.brokerId, req.session.passport.user.user_id, (req.body.amount).toFixed(0), function(sale){
        res.render('buying', {title: 'Buying', sale:sale});
    });    
});
```

`console.log('session user: ' +  req.session.passport.user);` logs:

> {"user_id":3,"type":"Normal","email":"khockenhull@gmail.com","firstname":"Kinnard","lastname":"Hockenhull"}`

But
`console.log('session user_id: ' +  req.session.passport.user.user_id);` logs:

> undefined

How is this possible and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`req.session.passport.user` seems to be a JSON string not a JavaScript object. Since string object has no `user_id` property it returns `undefined`. Parse the JSON using `JSON.parse` method then read the property.

```
JSON.parse(req.session.passport.user).user_id;
```

Comment: That worked. How did you know that req.session.passport.user was a JSON string?

Comment: The logged value was a valid JSON and the property returned `undefined`. This means what you have should be a string. There is no other logical reason for having an `undefined` value in this case.